# cordova/phonegap block and allow back button

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, back-button

I am trying to block the back button in certain cases.

However as soon as I add the eventlistener it always blocks the back button.

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 function onDeviceReady() {
      document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKey, false);
 }

function onBackKey() {
    if($scope.quicksetup)
    {   
        alert("1");
        return false;
    }   
    else
    {   
        alert("2");
        return true;
    }   
}
```

It comes in the else structure but when it returns true it doesn't execute the back action anymore.

There are no errors whatsoever in logcat.
I have no idea what is causing this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you set the listener you overwrite the `backbutton` behaviour no matter if you return `true` or `false` it will not execute the normal way anymore.
You need to use `navigator.app.backHistory()` and `navigator.app.exitApp();` to handle going back and exiting the app.

The `onbackbutton` callback does not expect anything to be returned, it is **not** a `boolean` callback function.

```
function onBackKey() {
    if($scope.quicksetup)
    {   
        alert("1");
        return;
    }   
    else
    {   
        alert("2");
        navigator.app.exitApp(); //I guess you want to exit the app here
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick, if not in quicksetup wanted to process the backbutton so replaced exitApp with the backHistory and now works like a charm.

Comment: @GerardvandenBosch glad it helped :)